# $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right)^x$via fundamental limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am stuck on what to do to get to a $\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)^x$ form in order to use the fundamental limit, it must not be done using L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right)^x=\left(1+\frac{2a}{x-a}\right)^x=$$

$$=\left(1+\frac{2a}{x-a}\right)^{x-a}\left(1+\frac{2a}{x-a}\right)^a\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e^{2a}\cdot1=e^{2a}$$